# C++ method not calling member method but compiles fine

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

I'm building a Vulkan Project with CMake and C++. My project compiles fine under MSVC 2019. However, when calling this line:

```cpp
printf("Before\n"); // The below line is where the program hangs.
const char** e = this->validationLayers->getRequiredExtensions(); 
this->createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = e;
this->createInfo.enabledLayerCount = sizeof(e) / sizeof(e[0]);
```

I get all the outputs for creation of my program up to the "Before" output. The next two lines don't throw a compiler error, but exit my program immediately.

Definition

```cpp
const char* const* Dragon::dgVulkanValidationLayer::getRequiredExtensions() {
    printf("Method");
    return this->validationLayers.data();
}
```

Declaration

```cpp
namespace Dragon {
    class dgVulkanValidationLayer {
        public:
            ...
            const char* const* getRequiredExtensions();
            ...
        private:
        std::vector<const char*> validationLayers = {
            "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"
        };
    };
};
```

How do I fix this issue?

My debugger exits with this line.

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF6C2880953 in Exefile.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

EDIT: Clarification. The problem was not in how it was happening. the problem is that when calling the `getRequiredExtensions()` method the program exits immediately.

EDIT 2: So after struggling with my debugger for about a half hour, the line that throws the exception is one inside of the `vector.data()` method.

Comment: What is `this->validationLayers`? It can’t be the vector you show, the program wouldn’t compile.

Comment: The right point of time for learning how to use a debugger... The symptoms you describe typically occur if your have some objects not correctly initilalised. A first guess would be `this->validationLayers` pointer being either a null pointer or not initialised at all (containing garbage). With a debugger you could follow your application step by step and inspect the state of the variables. But with this little fragment of code it's impossible to give you more than a view hints at where to look. You shold have an eye on [mre]...

Comment: Aside from it not being clear what `validationLayers` is, `enabledLayerCount` is also calculated wrong. It should be the number of strings, i.e. `.size()` of the vector, not the `strlen` of the first entry.

Comment: both the declaration of `validatiionLayers` and `getRequiredExtensions()` are in a class called `dgVulkanValidationLayers` in the namespace `Dragon`. If I put a `println` on the first line of the `getRequiredExtensions` function, it is not printed. and by putting `.size()` instead of `strlen` it throws an error.

Comment: All those `this->`s give me a headache.

Comment: Just removed some of the excessive `this->`

Comment: More details may help:
1. Could you add what happens before the "Before"?
2. How does the program "just exit"?  With an exit code / signal / some Windows dialogue?  Can you run it under a debugger perhaps and get some more information about the exit?

Comment: clarified a bit more on this.

Comment: What is the value of `this`? Is *dgVulkanValidationLayer* allocated on the stack or the heap? If it is heap allocated is possible for `this` to be an invalid pointer and not crash for until memory is dereferenced (like in the `vector::data` function). Additionally you're still calculating *enabledLayerCount* wrong, `sizeof(char**)/sizeof(char*)` is likely going to be one.

Comment: All of the lines are enclosed within large classes. so the value of `this` actually refers to class instance members.

Comment: `this` is actually a pointer to your object passed to the function in RCX register in the Windows x64 ABI. Thus there is no guarantee that the program will crash immediately upon executing the function, and instead generally when you access a data member. In your debugger you should be able to inspect `this` to see what address it is pointing to, you can also break on the assembly at the function prolog and inspect the RCX register, or you can look at the call stack, see where it is being called, and view the pointer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*enabledLayerCount* is the number of elements in the *ppEnabledLayerNames* array, not the length of the first string. The value you should be assigning is `this->validationLayers.size()`.

[Here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap4.html#VUID-VkInstanceCreateInfo-ppEnabledLayerNames-parameter) <sub>[archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20220126051319/https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap4.html#VUID-VkInstanceCreateInfo-ppEnabledLayerNames-parameter)</sub> are the spec valid usage requirements for *ppEnabledLayerNames* and *enabledLayerCount*.

> If *enabledLayerCount* is not 0, *ppEnabledLayerNames* **must** be a valid pointer to an array of *enabledLayerCount* null-terminated UTF-8 strings

Additionally the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap4.html#VkInstanceCreateInfo) <sub>[archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20220126051319/https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap4.html#VkInstanceCreateInfo)</sub> for the *ppEnabledLayerNames* struct member says

> *ppEnabledLayerNames* is a pointer to an array of *enabledLayerCount* null-terminated UTF-8 strings containing the names of layers to enable for the created instance. The layers are loaded in the order they are listed in this array, with the first array element being the closest to the application, and the last array element being the closest to the driver. See the [Layers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap31.html#extendingvulkan-layers) <sub>[archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20220126051257/https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap31.html#extendingvulkan-layers)</sub> section for further details.